# Derivative of a partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Assuming that $\dot{x}=f(x,t,C)$, where $C$ is a parameter and $f(\cdot)$ is continuous, how do we show that

$$\frac{d}{dt} \bigg[\frac{d x}{d C} \bigg]=\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}+ \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{d x}{d C} \bigg)$$

Please prove it step by step.

Below is what I did.

Let $x=F(x_0,x,t,C)$. We have

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= f(x,t,C) \\
&= F_t+F_x\frac{d x}{d t}
\end{align}

as the initial value $x_0$ and $C$ are time invariant.

$$\frac{d}{dt} \bigg[\frac{d x}{d C} \bigg]=\frac{d}{d t} \bigg[\frac{\partial x}{\partial C} \bigg]+\frac{d}{d x} \bigg[\frac{\partial x}{\partial C} \bigg]\frac{d x}{d t}$$

I get stuck here.

Comment: There seems to be something confused here. If $C$ is a constant scalar, then any derivative with respect to it is $0$. Do you perhaps mean it is a scalar?

Comment: A scalar that is taken from some set is commonly called a parameter.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Yeah, $C$ represents unknown parameters of the nonlinear system above. I need to identify $C$ with the first equation in display mode but I don't know how the book deduces it. I have provided all relevant information in the book.

Comment: @ Changije GUAN I'm really out of practice doing calculations, what I tried the last 5 minutes resulted in lots of errors. I'm confident that someone who has more practice will answer your question easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for some time, I worked out the problem myself. I made a mistake above because $x=F(x_0,t,C)$ instead of $F(x_0,x,t,C)$. Hence,

$$\dot{x}=\frac{d F}{d t}=f(x,t,C)$$

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[\frac{d x}{d C}\bigg]=&\frac{d}{d t}\bigg[\frac{d x}{d C}\bigg]
=\frac{d^2x}{d td C}
\end{align}
Exchanging the order, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2x}{d Cd t}=&\frac{d}{d C}\bigg[\frac{d x}{d t}\bigg]\\
=&\frac{d}{d C}f(x,t,C)\\
=&\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}+\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{d x}{d C}\bigg)
\end{align}

Done!

Comment: After few weeks, I reviewed calculus and the book containing the equations in this question, found that the notation in that book was unclear and the author mistook total derivative with partial derivative. So I edited my question and answer to make it consistent.